# Rails: Getting list of attributes with uniqueness validations from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

Just wondering if it's possible to return a list of all attributes which possess a uniqueness validation? For example, I have a model Person - I'd like to return a list of the attributes in 'Person' which have a uniqueness constraint. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do something like

`Person.validators.select { |v| v.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator) }`

to get the list of uniqueness validators for the Person model. Each validator has an `@attributes` instance variable, and that's what you probably need.

Answer (score 0):

Building up on [@eugen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7104544/766301), here is the code to list all attributes with a uniqueness validator:

```rb
self.class.validators.collect do |validator|
  validator.attributes if validator.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Validations::UniquenessValidator)
end.flatten.compact.uniq
```

It returns an array of symbols, add `.map(&:to_s)` at the end to get an array of strings.